# gcloud composer command fails "executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to run backfilling an Airflow DAG on Cloud Composer. Am I missing something?

```
$ gcloud composer environments run myenv \
  --location  us-central1 --project myproject \
  backfill -- -s 2020-10-05T10:30 -e 2020-10-05T10:30 \
  -x -I mydag 
kubeconfig entry generated for us-central1-myenv-xxx-gke.
Executing within the following kubectl namespace: xxx
command terminated with exit code 126
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process
caused "exec: \"-s\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.run) kubectl returned non-zero status code.
```

I am using the following versions of CLI tools.

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 286.0.0
bq 2.0.55
core 2020.03.24
gsutil 4.48
```

Composer image version is `composer-1.8.3-airflow-1.10.3`.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to Airflow workers directly through `kubectl` command-line tool as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#viewing_installed_python_packages) and execute [backfill](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli.html#backfill) inside the particular Pod?

Comment: Yes it works but my question is why this command is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the latest google cloud SDK and Kubectl solved the issue

```
sudo apt-get install kubectl
sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to deeper investigate the problem in Airflow GKE container [runtime](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/kubernetes-engine-overview#workloads), I would recommend to invoke `gcloud composer environments run` command, switching to `debug` level of output verbosity.

```
gcloud composer environments run myenv --location us-central1 --project myproject --verbosity=debug backfill -- -s 2020-10-05T10:30 -e 2020-10-05T10:30 -x -I mydag
```

The command print out might give a chance to fetch up debug entries, researching the records with `kubectl` command line compositions:

> DEBUG: Executing command: [u'/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/kubectl',
>   u'--namespace', u'composer-1-8-3-airflow-1-10-3-xxxxxx', u'exec',
>   u'airflow-worker-xxxxxxxx', u'-tic', u'airflow-worker', u'airflow',
>   u'backfill', u'--', u'-s', u'2020-10-05T10:30', u'-e',
>   u'2020-10-05T10:30', u'-x', u'-I', u'test_dag']

The above output reflects a way how `gcloud` decouples command line arguments, dispatching them to `kubectl` command inheritor. Next, you can manually compose `kubectl` command call to particular Airflow worker Pod, based on these parameters:

```
kubectl --namespace composer-1-8-3-airflow-1-10-3-xxxxxx exec airflow-worker-xxxxxxxx -tic airflow-worker airflow backfill -- -s 2020-10-05T10:30 -e 2020-10-05T10:30 -x -I test_dag
```

Upon to the comments conversation, where mentioned that you was able to issue Airflow [backfill](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli.html#backfill) command via `kubectl` call hook successfully, I can assume that the problem could be related to the incorrect arguments retrieved from top `gcloud` by `kubectl` predecessor.

You can even try to replace `-s`, `-e` positional arguments with `--start_date` and `--end_date` respectively, due to the fact that for some unknown reason GKE nested OCI runtime recognized `-s` as an execution file in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by a recent change in `kubectl exec` that causes only the token after the end of options (`--`) to be interpreted as the executable. Since `gcloud composer environments run` internally uses `kubectl`, you can roll back to an older version of `kubectl` as a workaround (those who have it installed as a `gcloud` component - you can use [`gcloud components restore`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/restore)).

This is otherwise resolved in Cloud SDK release 288.0.0. Update to at least this version to fix the issue (you do *not* need to update `kubectl`). Run the following to update:

```
gcloud components update
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the old version of gcloudsdk like 283.0.0

I also had the same problem with version 287.0.0
After returning to using version 283.0.0, everything worked properly.